# How to fix Trust Boundary Violation flaw in Java Web application

Tags: java, security, veracode

I am receiving a Trust Boundary Violation from Veracode.
My code is

```
userName= req.getParameter(Constant.USERNAME);
session.setAttribute(Constant.USERNAME, userName); //At this line i am getting Trust Boundry Violation flaw.
```

How can I validate `userName` to avoid a trust boundary violation flaw?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a regular expression to validate the userName according to the rules your usernames follow:

```
if(userName.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z_]+")
     session.setAttribute(Constant.USERNAME, userName);
```

Comment: this matches a name only containing alphanumeric letters and underline. you should also write an else block that results in some error for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I applied this validation but still i am getting trust boundary vioaltion on the same line. Is there any other way to put value in something rather than in session because whereever i am getting this flaw at those places i am putting some value in session only. Please help me on this...

Comment: This signature is among the more meaningless ones. Tell your scanner folks this is nonsense and ask them to prove otherwise ;)

Comment: correct, after adding validation, the error from VeraCode is simply wrong.

Answer (score 2):

VeraCode will require you to file a mitigation with them. They will schedule a consultation with you and there you can show them the code fix(s) implemented and they will then mark the mitigation approved.

Yes, I know this is late but others may trip through and it needs to be pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Trust boundary violation happens when user input is set into session. Using this flaw attacker can set any other username in to session and can cause impersonation. Where ever username is accessed is code from `session(session.getattribute)` will give attacker privileges of that user.

**Mitigation**: before setting user input into session, make sure that username that is set in to session is of authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

Validate your data using  `ESAPI.validator().getValidInput(...)` and then set the value into a session object.