# How to fix checkmarx Trust Boundary Violation

Tags: java, regex, checkmarx, secure-coding

I persist a value from user input request. *Checkmarx* complains there is **Trust Boundary Violation**.

> gets user input from element request. This element’s value flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually stored in the server-side Session object

I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977207/how-to-fix-trust-boundary-violation-flaw-in-java-web-application) online.
The accepted answer is to validate it.

OK, validate and sanitize

```
private String getValidSearchPath(String searchPath) {
    if (!searchPath.matches("^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$")) { //using regex to do validation
        throw new RuntimeException("Unacceptable jsonPath " + searchPath);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(searchPath)) {
        return "";
    }
    return searchPath.substring(0,0); // I intentionally put 0,0 here, which returns "" 
}

...
//pseudo code
String searchPath = getValidSearchPath(request.get(...));
persistSearchPath(searchPath);
```

Then I run *Checkmarx* again.
Guess what? I still got **Trust Boundary Violation**. Can someone tell me how to fix it? I already return empty string and *Checkmarx* still complains that I am using value from user input improperly.

Comment: Basically, these two questions are about sanitizing the data by `if (not) return` pattern. [checkmarx cannot see the code in static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527043/checkmarx-cannot-see-the-code-in-static-method)

Answer (score 0):

Checkmarx searches for a set of validation and functions in code, one of them being the [ESAPI library](https://owasp.org/www-project-enterprise-security-api/). Use the ESAPI.getValidInput method to validate instead:

```
Validator.SafeString=^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$;

ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("Search Path", searchPath , "SafeString", maxLength, allowNull);
```